# What additional information would I need to calculate P(X|Y or Z) given P(X|Y) and P(X|Z)?

Tags: conditional-probability

Is this always true when Y, Z are independent?

$P(X|Y\cup Z) = P(X|Y) + P(X|Z)$

Comment: The title and the question don't seem to match... you might want to correct that.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely to be true

As a simple example, if $X,Y,Z$ are all mutually independent then

$P(X\mid Y\cup Z) = P(X) = \frac12\big(P(X\mid Y) + P(X \mid Z)\big)$

---

If you really want $P(X\mid Y\cup Z)$ then note it is  $\frac{P(X\cap (Y\cup Z))}{P(Y\cup Z)}$.

For the denominator, if $Y$ and $Z$ are independent then $P(Y\cup Z) = P(Y)+P(Z)-P(Y)P(Z)$, which may or may not be helpful.

For the numerator you have $P(X\cap (Y\cup Z))=P((X\cap Y)\cup(X\cap Z))$ with or without independence of $Y$ and $Z$, but this is unlikely to be more helpful

Comment: what additional information would I need to characterize $P(X|Y \cup Z)$

Comment: @Quesop: You need a lot more detail - see my addition to the answer

Answer (score 1):

No.  Consider $P(X) = 1$ regardless of $Y$ or $Z$.  Then $P(X|Y) + P(X|Z) = 2$, which does not equal $P(X|Y\cup Z)=1$.